# IIS 8.5 Request Entity is too large happens in IE 11 but not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, wildfly, iis-8.5

I keep encountering the error: "The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large." (413 error upon checking IIS logs) when connecting to my application using Internet Explorer but I do not get this error at all using Chrome. I am not uploading anything, I'm just accessing the site. Fiddler says that the Entity Size is 597 bytes only so this shouldn't be a problem.

My setup is as follows:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition
- IIS 8.5, Extended Protection: Accept; Kerberos enabled
- Application Server: Wildfly 8.2.0 Final

I've tried several suggested solutions from different questions here, Some of them are as follows:

- [IIS7 - (413) Request Entity Too Large | uploadReadAheadSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)
- [The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large. iis7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762311/the-page-was-not-displayed-because-the-request-entity-is-too-large-iis7)
- [Uploading large files error to wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928263/uploading-large-files-error-to-wildfly)
- https://forums.iis.net/t/1207889.aspx (I'm not sure if outside link is allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is the removal of Negotiate in the Providers. It is found in Server > Authentication > Providers (at the right pane).

[Sample image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IuZn.png)

I also updated the Advanced Setting of Authentication:

- Extended Protection: Off
- Enable Kernel-mode authentication: True